# Why I'm getting the error: "Parameter 1 to Credis_Client::scan() expected to be a reference"?

Tags: class, pointers

I'm trying to call this class function:

```
public function scan(&$Iterator, $pattern = null, $count = null)
{
    return $this->__call('scan', array(&$Iterator, $pattern, $count));
}
```

From my class:

```
$itScan = NULL;
while($arr_keys = $this->redisClient->scan($itScan, '', 10000)) {
    foreach($arr_keys as $str_key) {
        echo "Here is a key: $str_key\n";
    }
}
```

I understand this is something related to the & pointer but I can't figure who to call it from inside my class.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is the proper way to iterate over your results :

```
$i = null;
$allResults = [];

do {
    $someResults = $redis->scan($i, "*", 10000);
    if (!empty($someResults)) {
        $allKeys = array_merge($allKeys, $someResults);
    }
}
while ($i);
```